# <object> do not load pdf file until click

Tags: html, object, pdf

Goal: Load HTML page with

```
<object data="/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
```

but I don't want the server to start downloading the PDF(100mb) every time I load the page. Something like a button that allows users to view it if they choose to.

I want to avoid third party plugins, I want to try and achieve this as simply and vanilla as possible.

Comment: This actually will solve my issue, I didn't think about that. If you'd like, go ahead and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling this code from another page? If this works, add code to launch another browser with the page when a button is clicked.